# How long did it take the infected to starve in 28 Days Later?

Tags: plot-explanation, 28-days-later

At the end of the movie 28 Days Later, we see that many of the infected are starving. But how long did it actually take all of the infected to starve to death? The main character wakes up after 28 days in a hospital, and then some time passes when he meets new people. But then even more time has passed when we see the jet fly over at the end. We know that the infection is wiped out, well almost, by the sequel 28 Weeks Later, but that is a long time for all of the infected to have survived with no food. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have any evidence for this yet, but it was always my impression that the 28 days also indicated how long it took an infected to starve to death.

Comment: That could be, but I thought he was in the hospital for 28 days. And when he got out, there were still plenty of infected...though now that I think about it, they would have been eating bodies. So I guess some of them would have starved by that point.

Comment: Exactly, every single one would have to be completely deprived of a food source for at-least 28 days. If even one eats something, that one can survive to spread the virus and create a whole new outbreak (as seen in 28 weeks later).

Comment: You are correct. I re-read my question and realized that I was not clear enough. What I meant to ask was how long did it take all of them to starve out, so not just an individual.

Answer (score 3):

I actually just watched the sequel 28 Weeks Later a few days ago. In the beginning of it showed: "5 weeks later: The infected have died of starvation" - so about 35 days.

Comment: How do you get 37 days

Comment: Sorry about 35 days - I was always horrible at math lol

Comment: why would they not die of thirst sooner -- would they be able to open a water bottle or turn a tap and even if they could turn a tap, wouldn't the water system stop working as in fact we saw with the father and daughter who were collecting rain water.